# Spanning tree protocol

Tags: spanning-tree, networking

I have a questions regarding STP and i would like to know if STP is only a feature of layer 2 switches? i am on GNS3 and i am trying to enable STP but it tells me that there is no spanning tree protocol enable, i am using a switch layer 3, and i am wondering, if i have to creat a vlan, and assigne STP on interface level ?

sorry for the basic question.

i am new to networking.

Comment: You would need to disable it on a VLAN before you could enable it on the VLAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A layer-3 switch is a layer-2 switch with added routing functionality - for L2, both behave exactly alike. However, when you create a *routed or L3 port* that port cannot participate in STP.

STP is required when a layer-2 network has redundant links (otherwise a bridge loop is created, causing a broadcast storm).

Answer (score 4):

Spanning tree is a layer 2 protocol.  A Cisco switch will enable it on a VLAN by default.

Comment: thank you and sorry for my ignorance, but and what about a cisco layer 3 switch?

Comment: If your ports are layer 3, there is no spanning tree.  If you create a VLAN and assign ports to it, then you will use spanning tree.